# Pyttsx3 show modulenotfounderror

Tags: python

I am trying to use pyttsx3 library and run the following code

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)
```

I getting this error

```
C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe C:/Users/Hp/PycharmProjects/miniproject/asad.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Hp/PycharmProjects/miniproject/asad.py", line 1, in <module>
import pyttsx3
File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from .engine import Engine
 File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\engine.py", line 1, in <module>
import driver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'driver'
```

Comment: That traceback doesn't match what's seen in the [source code](https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3/blame/067ad9085f614ff9308a4f1b76f6fd5dff2311ed/pyttsx3/engine.py#L1).

Comment: You have to update the library. The "import driver" isn't part of the current code (see https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3/blob/master/pyttsx3/engine.py).

Answer (score 0):

the error you see (ImportError: No module named 'drivers') is addressed by the following commit

[click](https://github.com/jpercent/pyttsx/commit/f035083338f39f7d93b0c610fbef0bb55fc9fc1c)

To install the pyttsx python module, you can

```
pip install git+git://github.com/jpercent/pyttsx.git
```

or

```
pip install git+https://github.com/jpercent/pyttsx.git
```

or

```
git clone https://github.com/jpercent/pyttsx.git 
cd pyttsx 
sudo python setup.py install
```

or do that inside a virtual environment if you use them. You can avoid using 'sudo' to install, depends on the environment you use and how you organized the packages (locations, etc.).
Of course, use the right python (python3) and pip (pip3) as you have in your environment.
Please remove and clean the previous pyttsx package you had there in the environment.
In addition, you can visit http://pyttsx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html
for more details on that.